# Unable to display the details of items

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var par = new Array(2);
par.push("Apple");
par.push("Orange");

var nar = new Array("2");
nar.push("red ");
nar.push("dark orange");

var ok = document.getElementById('one').value;

function abc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {

    if (par[i] == ok) {
      break;
    }

  }

  document.write(par[i] + " " + "color is  " + " " + nar[i]);


}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Enter the name</label>
  <input type="text" id="one">
  <input type="submit" onclick="abc()" id="on">

</body>

</html>
```

// In the above code snippets I am trying to display the color of apple and orange by defining the required details in an array but while running the code I  am getting output as "undefined color is undefined".I am unable to figure out the exact problem in my code.

Comment: move this line `document.write(par[i]+" "+"color is  "+" "+nar[i]);` inside the loop

Comment: Ali is right. Also, the query is case sensitive, keep that in mind.

Comment: for (var i=0;i<par.length;i++){
        var ok= document.getElementById('one').value;
        if(par[i]==ok){
            break;
        }
    }  // here break inside if statement will break for loop????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ist Statement you have used var par =new Array(2); This means it is creating 2 empty slots and then 2 values so creating array of length 4 . And in 2nd one you are using var par =new Array("2"); means ist value s string and then 2 value so creating array of length 3. So you are getting wrong result. Use new Array() this.  Also get the value of ok inside abc function

```js
 var par =new Array();
            par.push("Apple");
            par.push("Orange");

            var nar= new Array();
            nar.push("red ");
            nar.push("dark orange");

            function abc(){
var ok= document.getElementById('one').value;
        for (var i=0;i<par.length;i++){
            
            if(par[i]==ok){
                break;
            }
        }
        document.write(par[i]+" "+"color is  "+" "+nar[i]);
        }
```

```html
        <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Enter the name</label>
        <input type="text" id="one">
        <input type="submit" onclick="abc()" id="on">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot rupal ,but one thing I want to know break inside if loop will break the entire for loop???

Comment: Yes break statement breaks the recent loop in which it is defined

Comment: overall for loop will not run after break statement,it will get terminated.??

Comment: yes. it will not work. it is the functionality of break statement. It comes out from loop. Like if you are using 2 loop then if you are using break it will come out from recent loop. ex:- for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (var j=0;j<5;i++){

            
            if(i==2){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
break statement terminate the loop of j for i==3

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Enter the name</label>
        <input type="text" id="one">
        <input type="submit" onclick="abc()" id="on">
        <script>
        var par =new Array("Apple","Orange");


            var nar= new Array("red ","dark orange");

            var ok= document.getElementById('one').value;

            function abc(){
            for (var i=0;i<par.length;i++){

                if(par[i]==ok){
                    break;
                }
              document.write(par[i]+" "+"color is  "+" "+nar[i]);

            }




            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code after the loop ends `i,j` will be 2 and  `bar[2]` or `nar[2]` will be undefined  (accessing element of array with not existing index)

you need to move the write command to loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {

    if (par[i] == ok) {
        break;
    }

    document.write(par[i] + " " + "color is  " + " " + nar[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you define `ok` outside the `abc()` function. At the time you define it (as the pages loads), the input is empty.
When you click on your submit button, `ok` is still the value of the input as it loaded.
The following should work :

```
        function abc(){

        for (var i=0;i<par.length;i++){
            var ok= document.getElementById('one').value;
            if(par[i]==ok){
                break;
            }
        }
        document.write(par[i]+" "+"color is  "+" "+nar[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Its working ,but I am not getting valid color i.e for apple I am getting dark orange color

Comment: beacause you have used different array size. I have explained it with code snippet @alex

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't see that one ! @Rupal

Comment: Thanks. Also why to gett value of ok in for loop. you can use it inside abc but outside for loop.

Comment: That was also a mistake on my side... Copy-paste gone too fast.